# Recording both mic and system sound in ShareX

Tags: windows, screen-recording

How to record both microphone and system sound using shareX?
In shareX, under screen-recorder settings, I see two options:

1. virtual-audio-adapter
2. Microphone

When `virtual-audio-adapter` is selected, it only records the system sound. When `Microphone` is selected, it only records the microphone. I am unable to find any way.

Answer (score 4):

Open ShareX --> Task settings screen. Then follow the below steps. Paste this:

```
-f dshow -i audio="<replace your audio>" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest
```

For example in my case:

```
-f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but somehow the audio from the microphone is out of sync.